# ValueError: Not enough indexers for scalar access (setting)

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I'm having this annoying error with the following code:

```
def tag_df(sorted_cosine_similarities, data):
    tagged = list()
    n = len(data)
    print("Elements in collection:{}".format(n))
    for i in range(n):
        index, cosine_sim_val = sorted_cosine_similarities[i]
        data.at[index, "common"] = float(round(cosine_sim_val, 3))
    return data
```

where `sorted_cosine_similarities` is a tuple list and index is an index from data (pandas dataframe)

I think the `.at` is causing the issue.

The error stack is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-937a944a8e5e> in <module>
----> 1 tagged_set = tag_df(sorted_cosine_similarities, data)

<ipython-input-77-64f01d0d0fe8> in tag_df(sorted_cosine_similarities, data)
      5     for i in range(n):
      6         index, cosine_sim_val = sorted_cosine_similarities[i]
----> 7         data.at[index, "common"] = float(round(cosine_sim_val, 3))
      8     return data

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/traces_by_analytics-Mso168UE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2189             key = _tuplify(self.ndim, key)
   2190         if len(key) != self.ndim:
-> 2191             raise ValueError("Not enough indexers for scalar access (setting)!")
   2192         key = list(self._convert_key(key, is_setter=True))
   2193         key.append(value)

ValueError: Not enough indexers for scalar access (setting)!
```

Comment: Please add a few rows from your dataframe to the post, so users can test your code with the same data that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.loc[index, ["common"] ] = float(round(cosine_sim_val, 3))
```

Try above.